# How to post a list in post request flutter with http like this parameter "test_id[]"?

Tags: flutter, http, postman, http-post

```
'patient_age': patientAge!,
    'test_date': testdate!,
    "test_id[]": testIDs[0].toString(),
```

The API I got takes `test_id[]` repeatedly for list of test ids in body and in postman the API testing is working fine.
But when I try this `test_id[]` in body it shows map doesn't accept same key. How can I send a list in this pattern?

[image: See The pattern in postman - screenshot]

Comment: It's really not recommended to use duplicate keys. If possible I would change the api. It gives all kind of problems like the one you are encountering. I don't know who made the api but it really is a bad design like that. Instead of `"test_id[]":"7"` and `"test_id[]":"3"` it is much more conventional to just have `"test_id": ["7","3"]`

Comment: I think we should change how to write receive in api, like: `"test_ids":[1,2,3]` I had such a case, I requested it and both work fine. =))

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
"test_id":testIDs
```

- key is test_id
- value is testIDs (data type is List)

Comment: 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast . When I am trying to send a list it showing  type should be String . when I used  "test_id[]": testIDs[0].toString(), api is working .

Comment: Just add : "test_id" : testIDs.toString()

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in HttpClient from the `http` package (c.f. https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/47).

However, it seems that it's possible using the `dio` package: https://pub.dev/documentation/dio/latest/dio/ListFormat.html